# CakePhp find deep with all linked elements

Tags: php, cakephp

hope you can help me.
I have a little problem finding all elements belonging to one model.

I have a model 'Book' and it has multiple 'Text' elements.
Each 'Text' may have a subtext and there is no limitation to the depth.

So it might look like this:

```
Book1
 - Text 1
  - Text 1.1
  - Text 1.2
   - Text 1.2.1
    - Text 1.2.1.1
 - Text 2
```

Now I am looking for a way to get the 'Book' with ALL subtexts to print it out.
I tried 'Containable' but it only worked for two sublevels. Recursive=2 is not working either for deeper levels.

And TreeBehaviour is (in my opinion) not really what I am looking for, because I dont have 'left' and 'right', all I have is a parent.

Any ideas how to realize this? Could not find anything similar here on SO :/

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your example looks like you very well have left's and right's.

Comment: to be honest, it indeed shows something similar in the example of the cakephp site. but there must be a way to do this without a tree view?

Comment: Sure, using recursive queries (not sure whether the `recursive` option applies in case of self-associations), but it should be obvious that this really sucks, and that's where stuff like MPTT comes in handy, it allows you to easily fetch all children of a specific node with a single query.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating my own model function to go (or "findAllByParentId") through all the objects down to the bottom of the list. might not be the fastest way, but it is working